# Jest: How to mock custom module that is exported from an index.js file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is the structure of my project (create-react-app):

[image]

Contents of /src/api/searchAPI.js:

```js
import client from './client';

async function searchMulti(query, options = {}) {
  options.query = query;
  return await client.get('/search/multi', options);
}

export default {
  searchMulti
};
```

Contents of /src/api/index.js:

```js
import movieAPI from './movieAPI';
import personAPI from './personAPI';
import searchAPI from './searchAPI';
import configurationAPI from './configurationAPI';

export { movieAPI, personAPI, searchAPI, configurationAPI };
```

QuickSearch component imports **searchAPI** ands uses it to fetch some data over the web.

Now, I need to test (with *react-testing-library*) the QuickSearch component.

So, I would like to mock the **api** module (exported in /src/api/index.js) in order to use a mock function instead of *searchAPI.searchMulti( )*.

If I put below code in /src/componentns/__tests__/QuickSearch.js, it works just fine:

```js
...
import { searchAPI } from '../../
...
...
jest.mock('../../api', () => {
  return {
    searchAPI: {
      searchMulti: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ results: [] })
    }
  };
});

...

it('some test', () => {
  searchAPI.searchMulti.mockResolvedValueOnce({ results: [] });

  const { queryByTitle, getByPlaceholderText } = renderWithRouter(
    <QuickSearch />
  );

  const input = getByPlaceholderText(/Search for a movie or person/i);

  expect(searchAPI.searchMulti).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

  act(() => {
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'Aladdin' } });
  });

  expect(searchAPI.searchMulti).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

My problem is that I don't want to mock **api** in every test file that needs it. Instead, I would like to put **api** in a __mocks__ folder so that other tests can use it, too.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: @Gpx Yes, of course! I tried these 2 things but with no result:


1. Created a \_\_mocks\_\_ folder into /src/api, and placed inside it an index.js file which exports the mocked module.

2. Created a \_\_mocks\_\_ folder into /src, and placed inside it an index.js file which exports the mocked module.

Maybe, I do something wrong. I don't know :(

Comment: Without having access to the code I'm not sure what's the issue

Comment: @Gpx aahhhh, never mind. I figured it out.
All I had to do was to call jest.mock('../../api') in my test file.
It's clearly stated in [https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules), but I thought I had already tried that.